# Windows SDK 10 can not find .pcp file

Tags: sdk, windows-installer, installation, patch, msi-patch

Hi I have a problem I can not find template.pcp file that should be in windows SDK but It is not. I need it to make a patch .msp file I am following this tutorial: [MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/creating-a-patch-creation-properties-file) . Does anyone know where could I find it?

Comment: Belated, attempted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the **`template.pcp`** file anywhere in the SDK at this point, it might have gotten removed whereas [it previously kept being moved](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f15f7ef9-07db-4028-ba2a-ee9b4bb4916d/templatepcp-not-included-with-windows-sdk-for-vista?forum=winformssetup).

The free MSI SDK tool called **Orca** can save a PCP file - and other types of MSI-relevant files. Search Windows SDK folder for **`Orca-x86_en-us.msi`** and install. [Some more info here, current paths etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55399651/129130) (towards bottom).

WiX can also create a PCP file via markup, as explained in this thorough tutorial: [Using Patch Creation Properties](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/patch_building.html).  This tutorial should contain all required information to succeed without the `template.pcp` file (though I never use patching).

Comment: Great, I thought as much. Better with a late answer than never I suppose - for other people who might have the same problem.