# Why does clicking No in UAC prompt gives a error in MSI installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, installation

I have created a visual studio 2015 installer project. It creates two files after building. One is Msi file and other is setup.exe.

When I click setup.exe it gives a UAC prompt. If I click yes on that the installer works fine. But If I click No in that the installer gives an error. 
I am attaching images of error for reference. I have blackened client name for privacy.

[image: Files Images]

[image: Error Image]

Can anyone Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378972/how-to-install-files-even-though-user-clicks-no-in-uac-prompt-for-msi).

Comment: What does it say in that log file? If you don't elevate and your setup.exe needs elevation it exits ugly? Sort of expected behavior.